# How to apply WithTriviaFrom recursively for an IfStatement?

Tags: c#, roslyn

As you can see, only the if statement gets the leading trivia and not the rest of it:

**Input:**

```
            __Internal.DestroyContext(__arg0);
```

**Current result:**

```
            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
{
    __Internal32.DestroyContext(__arg0);
}
else
{
    __Internal64.DestroyContext(__arg0);
}
```

**Expected:**

```
            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            {
                __Internal32.DestroyContext(__arg0);
            }
            else
            {
                __Internal64.DestroyContext(__arg0);
            }
```

**Code used:**

```
var statement =
    IfStatement(GetImportCondition(),
            Block(ExpressionStatement(GetImportIdentifier32(invocation, name2))))
        .WithElse(ElseClause(
            Block(ExpressionStatement(GetImportIdentifier64(invocation, name2)))))
        .NormalizeWhitespace()
        .WithTriviaFrom(exp);

node = node.ReplaceNode(exp, statement);
```

If I remove `NormalizeWhitespace`, it works obviously but it isn't formatted anymore:

```
        if(IntPtr.Size==4){__Internal32.DestroyContext(__arg0);}else{__Internal64.DestroyContext(__arg0);}
```

**Question:**

How can one apply `WithTriviaFrom` recursively when used for an `IfStatement`?

Please don't suggest to normalize whitespace at root as this formats the whole document.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried just switching the order of `NormalizeWhitespace` and `WithTriviaFrom`?

Comment: Yes I tried but that didn't produce the expected effect.